# Jest and React Testing Library in Next.js app: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm using Jest and RTL in my next.js app.
Installed and set-up as described in [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/testing#jest-and-react-testing-library) but my tests are failing.

**Note:** I'm importing 3rd party lib, when I comment it out the tests are passing

Error log:

```
 ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /Users/tair.bitan/git/taboola/products/nova/src/main/webapp/node_modules/swiper/react/swiper-react.js:13
    import { Swiper } from './swiper.js';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

As it says in the documentation, Next should set up and configure Jest under the hood so it's weird for me that I need to handle it myself (also tried to uninstall and reinstall the libs).

According to suggested solutions I have added two additional keys to the `jest.config.js` template provided by Next documentation :

```
testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
},
```

so the file looks like that:

```
// jest.config.js
const nextJest = require('next/jest')

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
    // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
    dir: './',
})

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
const customJestConfig = {
    // Add more setup options before each test is run
    // setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
    // if using TypeScript with a baseUrl set to the root directory then you need the below for alias' to work
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/'],
    testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/'],
}

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig)
```

Unfortunately the problem is not solved by that